# Dropdown list not showing default item

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, semantic-ui-react

I am using the semantic-ui-react dropdown list, which I have working just fine. The problem is, on my form I am pulling data from a database using the Mobx store.  I have a array setup for the options in the dropdown list.  when the form loads from the store the text field for the dropdown list is blank, if I click on the dropdown I can see that the selected option is highlight (bold).  How do I get the text field to show the default options.  I have included some code below if anyone can look at it and give me an idea of what I need to do.

Thanks for all your help.

Here is the code for the dropdown list:

```
<div className="col-sm-3">
  <div className="bg-primary text-white text-center">
    Driver
  </div>
<div>
  <Dropdown
    selection
    fluid
    id="driver"
    name="driver"
    ref="driver"
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    value={this.props.EquipmentStore.truck_detail.driver}
    options={this.props.EquipmentStore.driver_list}/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is how I am building the driver_list, I am basically getting a list of users from the database and create an array with value and text fields

```
let newUserItem = {
    value: getUser.id,
    text: getUser.first_name + " " + getUser.last_name
};
this.driver_list.push(newUserItem)
```

The value in the truck_detail.driver is a numberic value that the same value in the value field in the driver_list value field...that is all working fine, I can not get the text value to show in the text field for the dropdown list by default.

Here is the code that I use to build the options list:

```
async loadDriverList() {
    let endpoint = '/api/users/profile/?owner=True';
    this.driver_list.length = 0;
    let lookupOptions = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };
    try {
        const response = await fetch(endpoint, lookupOptions);
        const profile_list = await response.json();
        const userItem = {value:0, text:'Select Driver'};
        this.driver_list.push(userItem);
        let array_length = profile_list.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < array_length; i++) {
            let ownerId = profile_list[i].user;
            let endpoint = '/api/users/users/' + ownerId + '/';
            let userList = await fetch(endpoint, lookupOptions);
            let getUser = await userList.json();
            let newUserItem = {
                value: getUser.id,
                text: getUser.first_name + " " + getUser.last_name
            };
            this.driver_list.push(newUserItem)
        }
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post an example of the data that gets fed to the Dropdown?

Comment: I have edited my post to include the code for building the options list.  That code lives a MobX store.

Comment: And then you just feed some data to the dropdown eg: `const driver_list = [{text: 'Driver', value: 1}, {text: 'Driver 2', value: 2}]`? Does the text go before the value in the objects? Also, is `this.props.EquipmentStore.truck_detail.driver` a number like 2? Just a number, no key or anything?

Comment: It could just be something weird, like the dropdown expects text before value. Semantic can be really funny like that

Comment: Right now I am building the list with value then text, I would not have thought it would make any difference the order but I will try reversing the order and see what that does.  Yes `this.props.EquipmentStore.truck_detail.driver` is an integer number that relates to the value  in the driver_list.

Comment: It is interesting, I have changed the order of the list, to text, value.  That made no difference.  Then I added a Key value (as per there examples), that made no difference as well.  But I have noticed that the first time I call that form, it is blank, but the second time I call it, it is working how I would expect, with the text field filled in.

Comment: Sounds like a race condition? What happens if you condition the render of the dropdown with something like `{this.props.EquipmentStore.driver_list.length > 0 && <Dropdown />}`? Also not sure what you mean by 'first time I call it'

Comment: I've tried this in a sandbox, and when I initialize it with a value, it works just fine. https://codesandbox.io/s/53mo6657x

Comment: Okay I have fixed it...the problem was that the drivers_list was not getting populated by the time the form was rendered.  After all in order to populate the list i am using an api call to the database.  I moved the code to a different place in the chain and it is now working....thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Awesome, maybe post how you solved the race condition as the answer, just in case people run into a similar issue!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of conversation with Predrag Beocanin I have solved this issue.  What it boils down to is my form (with the Dropdown) was getting render before the options list was fully populated.  In my application I have a form that shows a list of items, once you click on the item it will render a detailed form of that listed item.  Originally I wall trying to populate my options list once you click on the item you wanted to view the details on.  Because the options list is basically a static list, I am now populating that list when you are view the first form. Now when you click on the item to view the Dropdown options are fully populated and working just as I had expected.

Thanks for your help Predrag.